# How to make a LMS platform LTI 1.3 compliant and integrate a learning tool with it?

Tags: oauth-2.0, lti, ims

Our LMS is currently LTI 1.1 compliant. We need to make it LTI 1.3 compliant. What all changes I'll have to make in order to make our platform LTI 1.3 compliant and how to get a tool configured using it.

Answer (score 1):

What LMS are you using?

Recently, in Chamilo LMS, we have added the LTI 1.3 and Advantage services from LTI 1.1

Check the changes in this PR https://github.com/chamilo/chamilo-lms/pull/3065
... or change to Chamilo :)

Answer (score 0):

IMSGlobal provides a ['Migration Guide'](https://www.imsglobal.org/spec/lti/v1p3/migr) that outlines the differences in the model and which pieces are equivalent to what is already present in your LTI 1.1 integration.